# CSV is not getting read properly in java using csvreader

Tags: java, csv

This is my code. I am not able to write it back to a csv. I have figured out that the problem is with the header matching in the if loop. The values are being read correctly nut the if loop is not getting satisfied when the headers are getting matched. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class FactsChecker {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    run();
}


static void run()
{
    Map <String,String> csvMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String csvPath = "resource/Sample.csv";
    String outputPath = "resource/Output.csv";
    String[] headers;
    try{
    CsvReader csvreader = new CsvReader("resource/Sample.csv");
    csvreader.readHeaders();
    headers = csvreader.getHeaders();
    String[] values;
    String key = null;
    String value = null;
    while (csvreader.readRecord()){`

        values = csvreader.getValues();
        System.out.println(headers[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            if (headers[i].equals("FCT_NAME")) {
                key = values[i];
            }
            if (headers[i].equals("FCT_TYPE")) {
                value = values[i];
            }
        }




        csvMap.put(key,value);

    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : csvMap.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
    }

Map<String,Entry> entryMap= new HashMap<String, Entry>();
for (String factKey:csvMap.keySet()){
    Entry entry = new Entry();
    entry.setFactName(factKey);
    String factType = csvMap.get(factKey);
    System.out.println(factKey);
    entry.setFactType(factType);
    entryMap.put(factKey, entry);

}

    CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(outputPath);
    for(String key1 : entryMap.keySet()){
        Entry entry = entryMap.get(key1);
        writer.writeRecord(new String[]{entry.getFactName(),entry.getFactType()});
    }
    writer.close();

}

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using contains instead of equals in case there is trailing or leading white space

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue .Try the below. Just remove this appended character from your header when you read it from csv and then compare.

```
if(headers[i].startswith("\uFEFF"){
headers[i].replace("\uFEFF","");
}
```